# DTLS handshake not completing - ORTC prototype

Tags: javascript, webrtc, dtls, ice-protocol, ortc

Firstly - apologies as I can't add ORTC tag as I don't have enough rep, so adding webrtc for now.  I have been experimenting with the ORTC prototype, but I have unfortunately hit a stumbling block :(

I have a very similar test application to the following, using the ORTC prototype plugin and javascript code:
http://ortc.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/ortc.html#rtcicetransportcontroller-example1* 
however I have just a single ortc.RTCIceTransport and ortc.RTCDtlsTransport object at the moment.

I have ICE completing against a C++ test application, but I am unable to either receive a Client Hello DTLS packet, nor am I able to get any responses to my Client Hello packets after ICE completes.  DTLS claims to have completed as the console logs it's in the connected state, but I'm dubious as I see no packets on the wire!

...or is it the intention that the DTLS handshake starts when I do:

```
// Set the audio and video send and receive parameters.  
audioSender.send(audioSendParams);
audioReceiver.receive(audioRecvParams);
```

?

My test application works fine against the Firefox and Chrome ICE and DTLS stacks.  I can post some/all of the javascript below if that would help, but I'm just wondering if anyone has seen (and/or fixed) similar issues with the ORTC prototype code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

How are you starting the DTLS Transport? Which role are you applying?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt502488(v=vs.85).aspx

Note that if you start the DTLS Transport with the role "auto" and you are "controlling" the call, your end point won't push any dtls client hello packets. The remote role must be set as "server", so your end has the client behaviour you expect.